# Adding new elements to a document but the form is just refreshing itself

Tags: javascript, form-submit, createelement

So, I want the user to be able to add a new paragraph when he/she clicks the Add button. I can see it's working when I click the button but after that the page refreshes itself, and then the supposedly new paragraph disappears.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Item Lister</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"\>

</head>
<body>

<h1>ITEM LIST</h1>

<div id="container">
<ol>

</ol>
</div>

</br>
<form>
  <input id="txtbox" type="text" name="txt"/>
</br>
  <button id="add_btn" type="submit" name="add"/>Add</button>
</form>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's its JS code:

```
add_btn.onclick = function(){
  var msg;
  msg = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
  var newListElement = document.createElement("li"); 

  var liText = document.createTextNode(msg); 

  newListElement.appendChild(liText); 
  document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].appendChild(newListElement); 


};
```

How do I add the new element after clicking the button?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `event.preventDefault();` ? Example https://jsfiddle.net/71k16o2o/ I have also changed your `</br>`'s to `<br/>` and removed the self closing on your `button`

Comment: Or you can use the `onsubmit` attribute on your form tag. `onsubmit="return false;"` Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lss3fen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `type="submit"`

Edit : Turns out that just removing the submit attribute is not enough.

It should be changed to : `type="button"` :

```
<button id="add_btn" type="button" name="add"/>Add</button>
```

Comment: Just removing the `type="submit"` doesn't appear to work. https://jsfiddle.net/43ktkm94/

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have in fact at least two options:

- Remove type="submit" as Bulent Vural already mentioned
- Or return false from your onClick handler